# DataTable with clickable TD, display controls on click with hide and update on blur using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatable

In the datatable columns are filled with values. When I am clicking on TD cell and getting the value of cell but the alert get repeated. But I want it one time only. Also the cell should get display with select option for first 2 columns and input text for another 2 columns with the TD cell value.

Below is the code and I have made an `onClick` event on each `TD` to get the value. But how should I make the alert should popup once and to display select option and input box.? Also how should get the controls hide when clicked on outside of datatable?

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        });

        function Edit(n) {
            $('.clickable').click(function (e) {
                var val1 = $(this).text();
                alert(val1);
                return;
            });
        }

    </script>
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="GridView">
            <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick="Edit('1')" class="clickable">Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('2')" class="clickable">System Architect</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('3')" class="clickable">Edinburgh</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('4')" class="clickable">61</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('5')" class="clickable">2011-04-25</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('6')" class="clickable">$320,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick="Edit('1')" class="clickable">Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('2')" class="clickable">Accountant</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('3')" class="clickable">Tokyo</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('4')" class="clickable">63</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('5')" class="clickable">2011-07-25</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('6')" class="clickable">$170,750</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td onclick="Edit('1')" class="clickable">Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('2')" class="clickable">Junior Technical Author</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('3')" class="clickable">San Francisco</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('4')" class="clickable">66</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('5')" class="clickable">2009-01-12</td>
                        <td onclick="Edit('6')">$86,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me) what you are asking. Can you provide a [mre] showing only the relevant code (and some data, please)? For example, why is there Excel related code in your question? Is that relevant to the _specific_ problem you are asking about? If not, then remove it from your MRE. What would a successful outcome look like? Can you show us (e.g. using static data) instead of only trying to describe it? You can also use [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) to make your MRE code runnable.

Comment: @andrewJames The question is edited with the `RunSnippet`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the edits - I saw your updates. Unfortunately, what you have provided is not a MRE. Also, when I try to run the code you have provided, it just throws a syntax error.

Comment: @andrewJames The error shown is for `https://stacksnippets.net/js` this path. But I didn't used this path anywhere in my code

Comment: You have a _syntax_ error in your code. Read the error message again.

Comment: You are using a Stack Snippet! That is why `https://stacksnippets.net/js` is mentioned. But the _error_ you need to fix is this: `"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"`. It even tells you which line of your code to look at: `"lineno": 63`.

Comment: OK - I guess the line number of the error is not very helpful. Suggestion: Edit your stack snippet code. The stack snippet panel has 4 sections: (1) HTML. (2) JavaScript. (3) CSS. (4) Output. Look at your JavaScript panel. It has quite a lot of HTML in it. That is causing the error message you see. Take a closer look at the [instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) I previously linked to, which describe how to create a stack snippet. Take note of the "_with no wrapper_" instructions, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, because I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve (especially regarding the drop-down functionality you mention).

But maybe this partial answer will point you in the right direction.

It handles editable cells.

```js
var my_data = [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "notes": "lorem ipsum",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "notes": "dolor sit amet",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  }
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  const originals = new Map(); // tracks edits

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: my_data,
    columns: [{
        title: "ID",
        data: "id"
      },
      {
        title: "Name",
        data: "name"
      },
      {
        title: "Office",
        data: "office"
      },
      {
        title: "Position",
        data: "position"
      },
      {
        title: "Notes",
        data: "notes"
      },
      {
        title: "Extn.",
        data: "extn"
      },
      {
        title: "Salary",
        data: "salary"
      }
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, rowIdx, colIdx) {
        td.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
        td.setAttribute('spellcheck', false);
        td.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
          originals.set(rowIdx + ':' + colIdx, e.target.textContent);
        });
        td.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
          if (originals.get(rowIdx + ':' + colIdx) !== e.target.textContent) {
            $('#example').DataTable().cell(rowIdx, colIdx).data(td.innerHTML);
          }
        });
      }
    }]

  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The Name, Office, Position, and Notes columns are editable. Just click on a cell to edit the contents. Click somewhere else to save the edits.

The code uses [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) to make data editable.

It uses a map to capture pre-edit values:

```
const originals = new Map();
```

This is just to avoid unnecessary work, if the user doesn't actually make an edit change to a cell.

The new value provided by the user's edits is saved back to the underlying DataTable using [`cell().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()):

```
$('#example').DataTable().cell(rowIdx, colIdx).data(td.innerHTML);
```

We don't even bother to re-draw the DataTable, after doing this, as the display is already up-to-date.

---

**Suggestion**

Take the above code and see if it works the way you need.

Then, if it does, maybe you can see if you can add drop-down logic, in a similar way. You can build a dropdown using the following basic approach:

```js
var arr = [
  {val : 0, text: ''},
  {val : 1, text: 'Edinburgh'},
  {val : 2, text: 'New York'}
];
var sel = $('<select>').appendTo(td);
$(arr).each(function() {
  sel.append($("<option>").attr('value',this.val).text(this.text));
});
```

Depending on what you actually need, I think there is probably a lot more logic needed - espeically to manage the changes between showing a drop-down and showing a plain (selected) value.

But I have not tried this (and I'm not sure I would even know how to do it, myself).

Maybe you can try for yourself and ask a new, *specific* question, if you run into a new *specific* problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rowData = table.row( $(this).closest('tr') ).data();
```